# C# class works in Unity, but not in Android build

Tags: unity, c#, android

I am using Unity to program a simple Android game in C#. Right now, all the game does is to randomly load one of 196 flags upon startup (view: https://hastebin.com/suxonayoce.cs or code below). This class file is currently the only class file there is. When I play the game in Unity everything works as expected (i.e. each time the game is started a random flag is displayed). However, when I build and run the game on my Android phone only the placeholder flag is displayed and never a randomly chosen one.

So far I've tried relaunching Unity, re-importing all assets, and recreating the game in a new project. Nothing of this has resolved the problem.

```
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
  private int _flagCount = 196;

  private string[] _ccTlds; 
  private void GenerateCctldsArray()
  {
    _ccTlds = new string[_flagCount];
    _ccTlds = File.ReadAllLines(@"Assets\ccTLDs.txt");
  }

  private void DisplayRandomFlagSprite()
  {
    // Randomly gets the file name of a flag.
    int flagArrayPosition = Random.Range(0, 195);
    string flagImageName = _ccTlds[flagArrayPosition];

    // Gets the sprite of the flag called "flagName".
    Sprite sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>(@"FlagSprites\" + flagImageName);

    // Loads the image associated with "flagName".
    FlagImage.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = sprite;
  }

  [SerializeField]
  private GameObject _flagImage;
  public GameObject FlagImage
  {
    get { return _flagImage; }
    set { _flagImage = value; }
  }

  private void Awake()
  {
    GenerateCctldsArray();
    DisplayRandomFlagSprite();
  }
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas why the games stops working when it is run on the phone and how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I don't have an Android test setup at present, so the following is speculation.

I suspect this has to do with how you're trying to read your text file.

The file exists at `{ProjectPath}\Assets\ccTLDs.txt` *on your development machine*, but that's not necessarily where the file gets packed into an Android build. In fact, if Unity can't detect anything referencing that text file, it might not include it in your game build at all (since it tries to prune unused assets)

So, instead of trying to load it from a path using File IO APIs, I'd recommend assigning the asset file to a `public TextAsset ccTLDs;` member variable you configure in the Inspector.

This ensures you have a portable reference to it that will work on any platform, and that Unity can see the reference so it doesn't try to prune it out of your build.

Then you can replace these lines:

```
_ccTlds = new string[_flagCount];                  // <-- This line does nothing useful
_ccTlds = File.ReadAllLines(@"Assets\ccTLDs.txt"); // (since it's immediately replaced)
```

with

```
_ccTlds = ccTLDs.text.Split(new[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: I just want to mention, that sometimes when you are trying to read/write files in a "custom way" android doesn't like it. I tried writing to a local file inside my project, and the android build would hung there and run infinitely. Not sure if this has anything to do with permissions, as you are messing with local project files, but there's definitely something going on there.

Answer (score 0):

I too believe there is something wrong in reading the file.

First things, first.Debug it.
When you read succesfully the file, show a text in the screen , etc.

Secondly use this for the applications path in Android.

```
 Application.persistentDataPath
```

Answer (score 0):

`_ccTlds = File.ReadAllLines(@"Assets\ccTLDs.txt");`

The reason this works in Unity is because Unity has all the folders, however, when you build the game, everything is compiled into smaller files and the assets folder as well as all other project folders get lost. There is no longer an assets folder when you build the game so it can't read it.

Instead you can use `Application.persistentDataPath` which will get the games data directory no matter what operating system you're using. For example on Windows it's typically: `C:/Users/(username)/AppData/LocalLow/(company name)/(game name)`

Note: company name and game name can be set inside the project settings.

Example: `_ccTlds = File.ReadAllLines(Application.persistentDataPath + "/ccTlds.cld"`

Also, you dont have to to use a txt, something more random may help to make the file look less generic, if you care which you may not. If this file is important though you should probably look into a [BinaryFormatter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter?view=net-8.0). Otherwise anyone can just edit the text file and break the game basically.

Note:
BinaryFormatter is obselete and has some security flaws, it may work for basic data but you may also want to consider some of the alternatives listed on the BinaryFormatter docs page.

Comment: Note that the top of the page you've linked says in bright red: "BinaryFormatter serialization is obsolete and should not be used." It contains unavoidable security flaws that could create vulnerabilities on players' devices.

Comment: Yes, `BinaryFormatter` is obselete because of the fact it will serialize anything, I forgot to mention it so I'll edit the question but there are alternatives listed on the page.

Answer (score -2):

It could be because you need to set a random seed before using the random range, [**considering this similar problem.**](https://forum.unity.com/threads/problems-with-random-numbers.21033/)

Although I think that UnityEngine.Random's seed is deprecated after 5.3, so maybe use the System.Random?

**Example with UnityEngine.Random:**

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float bias;

    public void GenerateRandom()
    {
#if !UNITY_EDITOR
        Random.seed = Input.acceleration.magnitude * (1f + bias); /// Maybe you could use the accelerometer to get the seed.
#endif

        float randomNumber = Random.Range(0.0f, 100.0f);
        Debug.Log(randomNumber.ToString());
    }
}
```

**Example with System.Random:**

```
public class SystemExample : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int maxRange;

    public void GenerateRandom()
    {
        /// Maybe you could use the accelerometer to get the seed.
        int seed = (int)(Input.acceleration.magnitude * (1f + bias));
        Random rng = new Random(seed);

        /// Returns a non-negative random integer that is less than the specified maximum.
        int randomIndex = Random.Next(maxRange);
        Debug.Log(randomIndex.ToString());
    }
}
```

[**To know more about random seeds**](https://www.quora.com/What-is-seed-in-random-number-generation). Hope it helps.

Comment: I believe that your solution might work in the case where one is generating the same "random" number(s) every single time. However, in my case, the image that shows is one that cannot be loaded no matter which number is generated as the image is not part of the array to which the random numbers are fed in. I think that my problem may be caused by inadequate permission, but I have not figured out how to test this hypothesis yet.

Comment: Setting a seed is not required when using UnityEngine.Random, so I doubt this would be the cause of the issue.